# docker volume prune not deleting unused volumes

Tags: docker-volume

My understanding is `docker volume prune` should delete volumes which are no longer associated with containers.

Locally I have

```bash
$ docker volume ls | head -n 2
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     0d4cd922a4ed3e970726b1edb860c7dda3ae1e47f812585d9517d512ae70d5cf
```

I confirm it doesn't have an associated container via

```bash
$ docker ps -a --filter volume=0d4cd922a4ed3e970726b1edb860c7dda3ae1e47f812585d9517d512ae70d5cf
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

therefore I expect this volume to be deleted, but alas

```bash
$ docker volume prune
WARNING! This will remove all local volumes not used by at least one container.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Total reclaimed space: 0B

$ docker volume ls | head -n 2
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     0d4cd922a4ed3e970726b1edb860c7dda3ae1e47f812585d9517d512ae70d5cf
```

what am I missing ?

Comment: Mind expanding on the close vote ?  This is most definitely programming/software dev related

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is probably the issue mentioned in the docker cli github repo here: https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/4028

Apparently docker version 23 no longer deletes anonymous volumes (like your volume seems to be) when running `docker volume prune`. To get the original behavior you can use `docker volume prune --filter all=1`.

Comment: wow thanks so much.  That thread was very helpful

Comment: docker volume prune -a , is the answer. As per the docs option -a "Remove all unused volumes, not just anonymous ones"